# JOI - Validating complex object

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I tried, and tried but can't figure it :(

This is the object I need to validate:

```
let body = {
    greeting:
        {
            stringValue: 'Hello !',
            stringListValues: [],
            binaryListValues: [],
            dataType: 'String'
        },
    newsletterId:
        {
            stringValue: '123456789',
            stringListValues: [],
            binaryListValues: [],
            dataType: 'String'
        }
};
```

I need to validate that there is a **greeting**, and that is has key **stringValue** and that is not empty. Other values I don't care.

Also, for the second object **newsletterId**, and that also has key **stringValue** and that is not empty. Other values I don't care.

I have come up with checking only root object, with this schema:

```
const schema = {
    greeting: Joi.required(),
    newsletterId: Joi.required()
};
```

I read many examples, but I was unable to find none that has this type of structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lets define a schema :

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    greeting: Joi.object({
       stringValue: Joi.string().required().empty(['', null]),
       stringListValues: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()),
       binaryListValues: Joi.array().items(Joi.binary())
    }).required(),
    newsletterId: // same as above
});
```

and test it like this :

```
Joi.validate(myObjectToTest, schema, function(error, cleanObject){
    console.log(error, cleanObject);
})
```

Full reference can be found here https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md

Comment: Got it to work. Is there maybe a way, to allow other objects (e.g. binaryListValues), even though I dont need them. Something like allowUnknown?

Comment: see the unknown property :  https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v9.0.4/API.md#objectunknownallow